# C++ pointers to different types

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have a function in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) that can return either a pointer to either an int, string, or double. What would be the return type for this function?

I would also like a variable that can store that return value once the function returns it. Should I just use the same type for that?

Comment: The return type would be `void *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only match is `void*`.

```
 void* pResult = foo();
```

To use the value later, you will have to cast to `int*`, `string*` or `double*`. So you need to keep track of the actual type in some way.

Answer (score 3):

One way is the `void*` way which is demonstrated in Philipp's answer

Another way is to encapsulate your type in a `object` which derives from some common base object(i.e. `Object` in `Java`, `QObject` in `Qt`), and let your function return the common base object.

`QObject obj = foo();`

Check the library you are using, maybe there are some existing common base classes you can use.

Btw, I think template functions is also a good way to solve your problem.